# How do I make my bluetooth headset be the default microphone when I turn it on?

Tags: bluetooth, microphone

I have a webcam with a built in microphone, which I don't want to use.  I have a wireless bluetooth headset.  When I need to join meetings, I turn on my wireless headset and use my webcam's video.  Right now I have to select my headset as the audio input every time I turn it on in sound settings.  Is there a way for it to default to the headset microphone as soon as it's connected?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid of me to forget to mention.  Ubuntu unity 22.04